# confusion of address of a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, pass-by-reference, datamember

I see a piece of code like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct person{
   int age;
   float weight;
};
int main(){
   struct person *personPtr, person1;
   personPtr = &person1;
   printf("Enter age: ");
   scanf("%d", &personPtr->age); // why use &personPtr->age, shouldn't it just be personPtr->age since personPtr is itself a pointer. 
   printf("Enter weight: ");
   scanf("%f", &personPtr->weight); // similarly here: should it be personPtr->weight instead. Why the & in front of personPtr, I thought & means address, so wouldn't it means address of the pointer which seems wrong here if we want to show the weight value. 
   printf("Displaying:\n");
   printf("Age: %d\n", personPtr->age);
   printf("weight: %f", personPtr->weight);
   // however if I do: printf("weight: %f", &personPtr->weight); this doesn't print the value of weight. So it has to do with the scanf function? 
   return 0;
}
```

the thing I don't understand is what are the difference between:
&personPtr->age and
personPtr->age

in the code above. I always see peresonPtr->age type of codes when I have a pointer to a struct and want to retrieve the inner variable of that struct.

So say I have a struct

```
struct A {
   int x;
   int y;
};

struct A f1;
struct A *f2 = &f1;
```

then I know I can do:

f2->x, f2->y to get the value of x, and y of the x, y variables inside the struct f1. But what does &f2->x, &f2->y?

Or the use of & in &personPtr->age has to do with the scanf function here? (because its use & inside the scanf function here.

could someone explains the difference and why use the &personPtr->age instead of personPtr->age.

Another example here, for example here in the Mutex function, I again see the &

```
uthread_mutex_t uthread_mutex_create () {
  uthread_mutex_t mutex = malloc (sizeof (struct uthread_mutex));
  mutex->holder = 0;
  mutex->reader_count = 0;
  spinlock_create   (&mutex->spinlock); \\ why &mutex, instead of just mutex?????
  uthread_initqueue (&mutex->waiter_queue);
  uthread_initqueue (&mutex->reader_waiter_queue);
  return mutex;
}
```

Comment: Re "*why &mutex*" So the function can modify `mutex`.

Answer (score 0):

`personPtr` is a pointer to the whole object `person1`

```
personPtr = &person1;
```

So this expression `personPtr->age` yields the data member `age` of the object `person1` which you need to pass to `scanf` by reference that is through a pointer to it

```
scanf("%d", &personPtr->age);
```

To make it more clear you may rewrite the expression like

```
scanf("%d", &( personPtr->age ));
```

That is the expression `&( personPtr->age )` yields the address of the data member `age` of the object `person1`. And the function scanf expects as its argument a pointer to the original object. Thus dereferencing the pointer the function will get a direct access to the original object (instead of a copy of the value of the object) that can be changed such a way.

Also consider the following demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int x )
{
    x = 10;
}

void g( int *px )
{
    *px = 10;
}

int main( void )
{
    int x = 0;

    printf( "Before calling f() x = %d\n", x );

    f( x );

    printf( "After  calling f() x = %d\n", x );

    printf( "Before calling g() x = %d\n", x );

    g( &x );

    printf( "After  calling g() x = %d\n", x );
}
```

The program output is

```
Before calling f() x = 0
After  calling f() x = 0
Before calling g() x = 0
After  calling g() x = 10
```

As the function `g` accepts the variable `x` by reference (`&x`) then dereferencing the pointer it can change the original variable `x`. On the other hand, the function `f` deals with a copy of the value of the original variable `x`. So changing the copy has no influence on the original variable `x`.

Answer (score 0):

In C `scanf()` requieres a pointer to be passed to it. Because `personPtr` is a pointer to a person struct,simply passing it `personPtr->age` would give `scanf` the **value** of person1's age field and not a pointer to it and so the compiler would complain that `scanf` requieres a pointer but was passed an integer.

By doing `&personPtr->age` you are passing `scanf` the **address** of the age field from `person1`. Because you passed it an address and not an integer this time, there is no compilation error.

> then I know I can do:
>
> f2->x, f2->y to get the value of x, and y of the x, y variables inside
> the struct f1. But what does &f2->x, &f2->y?

`&f2->x`, `&f2->y` would give you the **address** of the x and y fields respectively. In contrast, `f2->x`, `f2->y` would give you their **values**.

Similarly in your last example,

```
uthread_mutex_t mutex = malloc (sizeof (struct uthread_mutex));
```

because `malloc` returns a pointer to the start of the allocated chunk of memory, `mutex` is simply a pointer to an uninitialized `uthread_mutex` struct.

The function

```
spinlock_create(&mutex->spinlock);
```

takes a pointer as it's argument. That's why you must pass it `&mutex->spinlock` or formatted differently: `&(mutex->spinlock)`.

The same applies for the functions `uthread_initqueue();` and `uthread_initqueue();`